# Problem retrieving ABI array from API of etherscan

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, testnets, ropsten, etherscan

I deployed my contract on ropsten through metamask and solidity browser and published it on etherscan so I can import ABI code for my nodejs app and work accordingly. When I open my contract's ABI through the api link it gives me this-
[image]

What could be the problem??Its same for all contracts launched in ropsten..its working fine for mainnetwork. Does etherscan not support the APIs for testnetworks??

Comment: Maybe with some more explanation ... For now so at first sight, I use the ropsten and I haven't problems with the ABI's

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide it with an api key token. At the end of URL add the token that is given to you when you create an account on Etherscan. URL should end with

> "address=ConractAddress&apikey=YourApiKey"